# Use of two em dashes or em dash and comma in appositives embedded in lists

Tags: lists, em-dashes

I like dogs, cats—which are hairy—and hippos.

or

I like dogs, cats—which are hairy, and hippos.

Comment: This is such a weird sentence either way. What is the point of explaining that cats are hairy? Can't you assume the reader already knows that?

Comment: You might at least find out how to type an em dash on your computer if you are asking a question about them. Two hyphens is an ASCII substitute, but SE, like any modern website, accepts UTF-8. Try Googling how to do it for your operating system.

Comment: It's a simple example to show the concept. I also believe one of the uses of em-dashes is to show unnecessary information, so having this description for a cat would work. Content of the example aside, what's the correct or more proper usage?

Comment: Someone has to point out that it is a courtesy to those you wish to help you to put a little effort in yourself. Also good questions are not solely for the poster, but for others with a similar question. That is how SE works. A naive user might have thought two hyphens was really an em dash. Despite this I have, in fact, answered your question.

Comment: @sumelic perhaps a more appropriate wording might be "... cats--but only hairy ones--and hippos."  Now we have excluded those abominations such as the sphynx, the mexican hairless, the ukrainian levkoy, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The em dash in a sentence serves as a forceful break—more than a comma, less than a period, and about the same as a semicolon—but more theatrical. For the apposite part, use a pair of dashes as you would parentheses.

Correct: I like dogs, cats—which are hairy—and hippos.

In this use of the em dash, you are stepping away and returning: I like dogs, cats—*stepping away here to add* a side comment that adds to, and does not restrict, the preceding bit—and hippos.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase “which are hairy” is in apposition to cats. This is why you have enclosed it in punctuation marks. Whatever punctuation mark you choose should be used consistently on both sides to reflect this. Therefore your first alternative is preferable.